# Selenium/Magento - Sessionproblem during parallelisation

Tags: magento, selenium, webdriver

I have a standard Magento webshop which I want to test in my grid. So I set up 3 virtual machines on a powerful VM-Server: Win7, XP and Ubuntu.
If I run the test on a single machine to test the web shop everything works fine. It tests the basic checkout procedure (putting articles in the cart, enter customer data, order etc).
AS soon as I start the test on the 3 machines with Selenium Grid 50 % of the tests fail because of sporadic errors which appear. This error appears anywhere during the checkout procedure an it says that the cart is empty although articles have been put into the cart. This never happens if I test on one machine.

So, did anyone have similar experience? Anyone has a solution for this? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know Magento but I found their [demo](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/).  It sounds like all your users are sharing the same session. Are your virtual users all logging in with the same credentials?

Comment: yes, that is right. they all log in with the same credentials. do you mean, this could be the reason?

Comment: okay I tested it manually with the same credentials and that is indeed the problem. Thanks! I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

I havent used selenium but I had similar problem while using a load balancer on AWS.

It happens because when you log in, and if you have session information stored on file system(not in database), the session file is created only on one of the virtual instances. So if during the checkout process, request goes to an instance where the session file was not stored, it would find the cart empty and log you out.

Try storing the session information in database and see if the problem still persists.